# How to make a more efficient request in React to improve peformance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, rerender

so I put a `console.log('rendering')` in my `<Router />` component and it's logging 10 times, seems a lot. I noticed this is causing 6 re-renders

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRESTCountries()
  }, [])
```

this just makes a call to here: `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`

which is returning an array of size 250, which isn't massive but not too small either. I was wondering how I can make this more efficient? I'm not sure why it's causing 6 re-renders.

I was thinking of using a react memo, but not sure how that would be beneficial here?

any advice on how to reduce the number of re-renders would be great as it isn't helping performance

thanks

this is my component code:

// the different `fetchDatas` is fetching different pieces of information

```
export const MainRouter = ({
        fetchData1,
        fetchData2,
        fetchData3,
        fetchData4,
    }) => {
        const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
        const authenticatedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'))

        useEffect(() => {
            firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(user))
                    setLoaded(true)
                    fetchData1(user)
                    fetchData2(user)
                    fetchData3(user)
                    fetchData4(user)
                } else {
                    localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
                    setLoaded(true)
                }
            })
        }, [])

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchRESTCountries()
        }, [])

        const logUserOutFirebaseAndRedux = async () => {
            try {
                await firebaseApp.auth().signOut()
            } catch (e) {
                console.err(e)
            }
        }

        const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
            return authenticatedUser ? <Component {...rest} /> : <Redirect from="" to="/login" noThrow />
        }

        const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => <Component {...rest} />

        const notSharedMap = /^(?!.*(\/shared-map)).*$/
        const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
            html {
                overflow: ${({ location }) => (location.includes('visited') ? 'hidden' : 'auto')};
            }
            body {
                background: ${({ location }) => (location.includes('random-stats') ? '#041a24' : '#fff')};
            }
        `
        console.log('re render')

        return (
            <Router>
                <GlobalStyle location={window.location.pathname} />

                <PublicRoute
                    path={notSharedMap}
                    component={CONNECTED_Nav}
                    logUserOut={logUserOutFirebaseAndRedux}
                    location={window.location.pathname}
                />


                    <ProtectedRoute exact component={AccountContainer} path="/account" />
                    // many more routes like this
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    },
)
```

Comment: without seeing the relevant code, its impossible to tell what's causing the re-renders and how the number of re-renders could be reduced. Consider sharing a link to the codesandbox demo

Comment: @Yousaf let me add

Comment: @Yousaf added the code

Comment: @cybercoder _And when render again your component mounts again_ - that's not correct. Component only mounts once. Re-render of a component doesn't mounts it again.

Comment: @Yousaf, yes you right, I didn't attend to empty array ```[]``` as second arg.

Comment: Where is `fetchRESTCountries()` defined? Also note that if different `fetchData` functions  are updating the state in the parent component, it will cause a re-render in `MainRouter` component. You could use `useCallback` hook to memoize the `fetchData` functions in the parent component of `MainRouter` and wrap `mainRouter` component with `React.memo()`. Also keep in mind that if your app is running within  `StrictMode`, that will also cause extra re-renders in your app but only in development environemnt.

Answer (score 0):

Just like your `loaded` state, also add an indicator once `fetchRESTCountries()` is already called. Something like this:

```
const [areCountriesFetched, setAreCountriesFetched] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!areCountriesFetched) {
    fetchRESTCountries();
    setAreCountriesFetched(true);
  }
}, [areCountriesFetched, setAreCountriesFetched]); // these two, I think, are required to be added on the dependencies array by eslint
```

It's a common practice. But, it all depends on the logic you're implying.